# Include jars in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, jar, parent-child

So here is the scenario. 
I have a maven project for which I am using some(7) jars for unit testing. All these jars are present on maven remote/local(.m2) repository. and I have to add them individually as dependency.

I want to create a pom (parent) which contain these jars as dependency so that if I include this pom(parent) as dependency, all 7 dependencies are automatically resolved.

I tried this code but i think there are some issues with packaging type. (`pom` packaging didn't work either).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>some.package</groupId>
 <artifactId>full-PACK</artifactId>
 <version>1.1</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>

 <dependencies>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
   <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
   <version>3.21.0</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

 <!-- 6 more similar dependencies -->

 </dependencies>

</project>
```

I want this pom to just act as pointer, and this should resolve dependencies in their respective packages not in package of this pom. I don't want to create a fat jar for this pom.

Is there a way in which I can use this pom as kind of pointer so that it just tells project to import those 7 jars?

Comment: If your project (call it A) needs those 7 dependencies than it is the way it is..So now if someone else will use your project A as a dependency he will get all the dependencies and the problem is solved...Maybe I misunderstand a thing here?

Comment: dependencies in scope *testing* are **not** copied to the final distribution (as well as the code in `src/test/*`)

Comment: @khmarbaise my project A needs 7 dependencies in for test scope lets say new project B will need those dependencies again, I will have to again import 7 dependencies, I want to reduce this to one dependency(parent for 7 jars), and upload this pom on our organisation's maven repository. so any new project can just import 1 dependency instead of 7 individual dependencies.
I want to create that pom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested it, but following the Maven logic, this should work:

Create a project with packaging `pom` that references the 7 jars as `compile` dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>some.package</groupId>
 <artifactId>full-PACK</artifactId>
 <version>1.1</version>
 <packaging>pom</packaging>

 <dependencies>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
   <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
   <version>3.21.0</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>

 <!-- 6 more similar dependencies -->

 </dependencies>

</project>
```

Now declare a `test` dependency on this pom in your project like

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>some.package</groupId>
   <artifactId>full-PACK</artifactId>
   <version>1.1</version>
   <type>pom</type>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Your approach failed because `test` dependencies are not transitive. Have a look at the table on

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html